# CFFILE Upload to server not working

Tags: file-upload, server, coldfusion, cffile

I have a site running in coldfusion in which we are trying to move all the file uploads to a new server. whereas my server IP is xx.xx.x.80 and I am trying to upload files to xx.xx.x.82/Files. Here is my code to upload file

```
<cffile action="UPLOAD" Accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" destination="\\xx.xx.x.82\Files" filefield="form.FILEUPLOAD" strict="false" nameconflict="makeunique">
```

I am getting the following error message when I try to upload

> The destination //xx.xx.x.82/Files specified in the file's upload
>   action is invalid

I have read some blogs and they are suggesting to upload in local and move using CFHTTP whereas I hope we can do this using CFFILE upload itself. Please share your knowledge on this.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Using CF for this seems unnecessary.  Can't you use an ftp client like Filezilla?  Or, if you are using Windows, can't you connect to both servers and copy/cut and paste?

Comment: \\xx.xx.x.82\Files needs to be setup as a shared folder and the user that runs the CF service on xx.xx.x.80  has to have permission to access the share on your new server \\xx.xx.x.82\Files.

Comment: @DanBracuk I need a fileserver where it saves all the user uploads.

Comment: @RandyJohnson I am not sure how to find in which user my CF is running. Can you guide me?

Comment: If it's a Windows server, check the services applet.  The CF App service is probably running in the Local System context.  You'll want to update that to a user who can write to the destination and restart the service.

Comment: I am not in front of my linux machine, you should be able to go into the /etc/init.d directory and look at the CF startup script to get the user or do a ps ax and search for the CF process.  I think nobody is the default.  Sometimes people choose the root user or the apache user.